# Probability problem. Need help

Tags: probability

Given that $P(A)=0.4$ and $P(B|A)=0.5$. Hence find find $P(A' \cup B')$. How to do this one?

Comment: Why is it not 0.5...? (If they are disjoint)

Comment: Don't know nothing more given in that problem

Comment: What does "**After A has occurred** find $\rm P(A'\cup B')$" mean?

Comment: Question edited that is actually probability of B after A has occurred is 0.5

Comment: Shouldn't you then write $P(B \vert A) = 0.5$ then?

Comment: Yeah I know that can you give solution to problem please

Comment: If you know that, then edit and write that.  Does P (x $\cup $ y) mean the probability of either one or the other, or the probability of both?

Comment: See if my edit change your question then revert my changes.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh No its right thanks

Comment: Your welcome...

Comment: What happened? Was there independent?

Comment: @Bellmondo Though your answer is also right but there is nothing given about their independences in the book , but assuming them independent worked in my case, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ShubhamWagh Your Welcome... There is something wrong in your question. If it was $P(A|B)$ You need not independency. But if it is $P(B|A)$ you need it.

Comment: @Bellmondo I guess there is misprint in book . thanks I will remember it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A , B)}{P(A)}$

So $P(A,B)=0.2$ and the answer is $0.8$

Answer (score 0):

Use formula-

$P(A'\cup B') = 1- P(A\cap B)$

Here's how it drive.

$P(A'\cup B') = P(A\cap B)'$

= $1- P(A\cap B)$

Also P(B|A) = 0.5

$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ = 0.5

So $P(A\cap B)$ = 0.5 * 0.4 = 0.20

So in your case answer,

$P(A'\cup B') = 1- P(A\cap B)$

= 1 - 0.20 = 0.80

Comment: Are you sure that P(A intersection B) is  equal to P(A)P(B)?

Comment: Also it is P(B/A) =0.5

Comment: If these events are independent then yes.

Comment: Ok I read it wrong. Then edit your questions.